# Can't Determine Type of Tag in Android Studio (Kotlin build)

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I've read most other threads with the same questions but none of the solutions seems to work for me. Trying to build a signed bundle in Android Studio 7.3.1 with Gradle 7.4. It's the only error (or the first?) during build. I get the error twice, both in the style.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ToggleButton
        android:id="@+id/toggle_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Strobe"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/seekBar"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:min="100"
        android:max="300"
        android:layout_marginStart="64dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="64dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="32dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

EDIT:

This is my build.gradle. I must admit I had this build checked over by another developer on his computer, could I be missing an installation somewhere? Do I need the google repository in my build file? Ugh.. lost.

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
}

android {
    namespace 'com.example.someonestrobe'
    compileSdk 32

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.someonestrobe"
        minSdk 21
        targetSdk 32
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.7.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.6.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
}
```

Comment: You said the error was in your style.xml, but the code you posted is from a layout.

Comment: Hmm.. It's from app > src > main > res > style > style.xml. The <androidx> tag gives the error, not necessarily the ToggleButton. I'm guessing it's the gradle build.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the style.xml wasn't supposed to be there, it was a weird leftover from a previous build from another developer in the team. As noted in the comments: it was a layout code in a xml file. Deleted the style.xml and everything works fine. Only help I can give others: file management.